# unittest mock how to mock a method being called

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I want to test that method `a` calls method `b`. These methods are in separate files, and are not a part of class object.

```
# file_a.py
from file_b import b

def a():
    b()
```

```
# file_b.py
def b():
    test
```

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from file_a import a

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('file_b.b')
    def test_b_called(self, mock):
        a()
        mock.assert_called()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This fails with `AssertionError: Expected 'b' to have been called.`

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: Patch `file_a.b`, not `file_b.b`. You would patch `file_b.b` if you had done: `import file_b; file_b.b()` instead of importing the function into the current namespace.

Comment: @jordanm that worked perfectly, thanks! Please make this the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a function into the current namespace, like in your example, the function will need to be patched in that namespace. In your case, you need:

```
@mock.patch('file_a.b')
```

You would patch `file_b.b` if you had done the import and use like this:

```
import file_b
def a():
    file_b.b()
```

Comment: @chepner I just tested locally and what I have in the answer worked. Patching `file_a.file_b.b` did not.